# Run Excel macro on multiple excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I am a total VBA novice and I really need some help with this problem.

I have 100 excel files that contain 5 worksheets in each of them. I want to change the Cell C-24 of the 3rd worksheet (of all excel files which has the same template) from Red Font to negative numbers.

The red Font values of Cell C24 to negative values and rest of them as positive values. (color coding logic is consistent where Red Font is negative and Green Font is positive)

Below is the code which is giving me an error;

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim Filename, Pathname As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Pathname = "C:\CY 2018\12-Dec\"
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xls*")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
        DoWork wb
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Doevents
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)
    With wb.Sheets(3).Select   
    Value = Replace(objXLWs.Cells(24, "C").Text, vbLf, "<br>")
    If Value.Fore.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
    'nt.Color = vbRed Then  
    'If Value.Font.Color = vbRed Then
    Value = -(Value)         
    End With
End Sub
```

[Sample Excel file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eIJ7PXRrB55i6qB9aJ1ugLaxz0C_u1Qj/view?usp=sharing)
**Attached is the template for reference**

Where I'm doing wrong here. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated?

Comment: Note that `Dim Filename, Pathname As String` only declares `Pathname As String` but `Filename As Variant`. In VBA you must specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim Filename As String, Pathname As String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be due to the existing formatting of the cells. 
Try the below code

```
    Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)
        With wb.Sheets(3).Range("C24") 'there is no need to select the sheet
            'include your other code here
            'Add this to address the format
            .NumberFormat = "0.00" 'this will show negative numbers with a minus, make it just 0 if you dont want decimal points
            '.NumberFormat = "0.00;[Red]0.00" 'this will show negative numbers in red font
        End With
    End Sub
```

**EDIT**
Code updated to address all possibilities (hopefully)
checks for number format, conditional format or just font coloured red.

```
Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)
    Dim bolMakeNeg As Boolean
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    bolMakeNeg = False
    'if the cell are merged this will extract the value
    If wb.Sheets("3. NCC's").Range("C24").MergeCells Then
        Set rng = wb.Sheets("3. NCC's").Range("C24").MergeArea
        V = rng.Cells(1, 1).Value
    Else
        Set rng = wb.Sheets("3. NCC's").Range("C24")
        V = rng.Value
    End If

    With rng 'obtain reference to the cell
            'check if the value of the cell is negative
            If V < 0 Then 'if this is a negative value, this will sort out problem if number formatting is making it red
                bolMakeNeg = True
            ElseIf .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Or .DisplayFormat.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then 'if there is a conditional formatting the display format should point to the color displayed
                bolMakeNeg = True
            End If
            If bolMakeNeg Then
               'set number format
               .NumberFormat = "#,##0;-#,##0"  'change decimals as required
               If V > 0 Then   'set negative value
                .Value = -1 * V
               End If
               '*************
               'Add other code to set font face etc.
               rng.Font.Name = "Arial"
               rng.Font.Size = 9
               rng.Font.Bold = True
               '*************
            End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I've included the Number format but I see no negative numbers for Red Font value

Comment: The value is not changing to negative value, I've tried your code, attached is the excel for your reference Sheet(3) - Cell C24

Comment: thanks for sharing the excel, it was easier to figure out the issue(s) now. 1) The sheet reference used (3) is incorrect as the sheet reference in 5. I suggest that you use the sheet name instead as shown in the code. 2) The cell  you were referring to is a merged cell and probably the reason the .value did not work. This has been addressed in the updated code. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your DoWork sub with this

```
Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)
    Sheets(3).Range("C24").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_ ;[Red]-#,##0.00 "
End Sub
```

Comment: The macro is running without any error. But the Cell C-24 in the worksheet didn't change the red font values to negative values

Comment: Can we add Sheet Name instead Sheet number. The sheet name is "NCC"

Comment: I tested this and got the result as requested. without a clear picture of what's going wrong, it's hard to determine what's not working on your end. the Sheet name wont matter if it's consistently the 3rd sheet of the workbook. maybe make sure **the file with the macro** is **not** the first file in the folder you want to loop through?

Comment: The code is working fine, but I am not seeing negative values. My Red Colored Values are not changing to negative values

Comment: The code is working fine but I dont understand why I'm not able to see negative values. Look at the attached excel for your reference Sheet(3) - Cell C24

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing where your error is occurring, at a glance I can tell you that

```
Value = Replace(objXLWs.Cells(24, "C").Text, vbLf, "<br>")
If Value.Fore.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
'nt.Color = vbRed Then  
'If Value.Font.Color = vbRed Then
Value = -(Value)         
End With
```

Is missing an `End If` right before your `End With` (it really helps to indent).

Outside of that, I don't see anywhere where the variable `objXLws` or `Value` are initialized, for which I would recommend placing an `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module. Declaring variables is important.

Additionally, I doubt you even need `Value` or `objXLWs` as variables at all, since all you're doing is reversing the sign and changing the color. Also, the syntax for changing cell font color is `Cell.Font.Color = RGB()`

Something that might work better for you would be

```
Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)
    With wb.Sheets(3)   
        If .Cells(24, "C").Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
            .Cells(24, "C") = .Cells(24, "C") * -1
        End if
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to change the Font color (Red) into a negative number, not the cell color. Should I use .Cells(24, "C").write(rgb(255,30,30)) = RGB(255,0,0)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the word "Font" in "cell font color". This will change just the number, not the cell color itself.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that if your worksheets have conditional formatting or custom formatting on them that is changing the format based on the cell value then you probably won't see the results you're looking for and will need to programmatically disable that as well.

Comment: It doesn't give you an error number or description or anything?

Comment: How can I attach the sample template and the code I've used here

Comment: Updated my answer. Try it now.

Comment: It is working now, but I am not seeing negative numbers, attached is the excel for your reference Sheet(3) - Cell C24